# Angular route 404 error but all files available

Tags: angularjs, node.js

**EDIT:** The initial problem have now been fixed, I.E. he routes works now (it was a matter of a missing e in templat(e)Url
However, still gets that GET 404 issue, tried the html://localhost:3003/#/contactus but can't get that to work. Backend is node and express.

Going insane here, so trying to build a simple single page app, and so far haven't even gotten the index page working. 
I am continuously getting GET / 404

I am certain that there is something rather ridiculous that I have missed. 
In the node app, I have set up the routes to use partials and a catch all /*

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.get('*', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/partials', partials);
```

With the route controllers as follows
"index.js" (loaded as routes)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
exports.index = function(req, res){
    console.log("This is a test");
    res.render('layout');
};



module.exports = router;
```

And partials.js (loaded as partials)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    console.log("Was asked to send /partials/" + name);
    res.render('partials/' + name)
});

module.exports = router;
```

The partials works. If I try localhost:3003/partials/about it loads nicely

So now to the layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="BabyPadz")
  head
      base(href="/")
      title BabyPadz
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
      script(src='/bower_components/angular/angular.js')
      script(src='/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
      script(src='/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js')
      script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
      script(src='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
      script(src='/javascripts/BabyPadz.js')
      //link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
      div.container
          ng-view
```

It does read this, when I access the page all the components loads (I even tried going to each and every one of them just in case).

Then BabyPadz.js, the angular controller

```
    var BabyPadz = angular.module('BabyPadz', ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl : 'partials/about.jade',
                    controller  : 'BabyIndex'
                })
                .when('/about', {
                    templatUrl : 'partials/about.jade',
                    controller : 'BabyIndex'
                })
                .when('/contact-us', {
                    templatUrl : 'partials/contactus.jade',
                    controller : 'BabyIndex'
                })

                // route for the about page

                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
        }
    ]
);
```

But, when I open the webpage, I get a GET / 404 error, and it seems like it does the redirect afterwards, which then loads index (or which ever page I put in .when( (in the above case about)

If I try localhost:3003/about or localhost:3003/#about I get a fail on the server. And sometimes a "failed to load resource localhost:3003/about"

Comment: To debug this, i'd suggest looking at the network tab in the developper console to see what the app tries to load. Did you try putting the templateUrl this way ? './partials/about.jade' or './partials/about'

Comment: tried setting the templateUrl to ./partials/about.jade and ./partials/about. No luck

Comment: Renan: You got me thinking, and I booted up another app I wrote (which code I stole as basic for this one) and it does the same thing, it asks for /, gets a 404, then loads all the modules, then calls for the partial. For some reason this app does not do it, almost like it haven't understood that it should get around to it, other than when I call /

Comment: OK, one step forward, five steps back. for some reason, it is only the first route above that works. the redirect works as well, and by playing around I can tell that the system does recognise all three routes in Angular (/ /about /contactus). If I change them I change the behaviour. However, when it does index (/) I can see on the server that it requests the partial, for the other ones it does not. So its almost like it reads the route but it is not registered or it does not know what to do with it.

Comment: OK, I still get the 404 error message on GET, but it works now. The problem you ask, well, spelling. `templatUrl : 'partials/about.jade',` should be `templat`e`Url : 'partials/about.jade',` (jupp, there is a missing e, if you did not notice it, don't worry, I missed it for the last four hours.

Comment: Haha that's when you want to give up programming and go to Morocco to just raise goats.

Comment: How did you know I was heading for Morocco?... Yes, not the best of days, at least it works now.